# e.keyCode branch not covered javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

*To clarify: I'm not using JQuery only pure JS, I need help to the unit test because to block the "enter" key works fine.*

I'm stuck in the unit test, I'm trying to figure how to cover the "branch not covered" in the unit test for the addEventListener keyCode = 13, to prevent to the user press enter and submit accidentally the form, but I'm very newbie with the unit test, can someone help me ?

Here the code:

Newsletter.js

```
var Newsletter = (function () {
  function Newsletter(handler) {
    this.handler = handler;
    this.blockKeyEnter = this.blockKeyEnter.bind(this);

    this.handler.addEventListener('keypress', this.blockKeyEnter, false);
  }

  Newsletter.prototype.blockKeyEnter = function blockKeyEnter(e) {
    var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;
    if (key === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };
}
```

Newsletter.spec.js

```
describe('Newsletter component specification', function () {
  var form;

  beforeEach(function () {

    form = {
      addEventListener: function () {},
    };
  })

  it('should intercept enter keypress event and prevent it', function () {
    var event = {
      keyCode: 13,
      charCode: 13,
      preventDefault: sinon.spy()
    };

    var newLetter = new Newsletter(form);
    newLetter.blockKeyEnter(event);

    assert(event.preventDefault.called);
  });
}
```

I'm trying to full the "branch not covered" but I lack of ideas to progress.

[image: branch_not_covered]

Comment: Seems like your unit tests don't understand the logical OR. How, and with what, are you testing this

Comment: To be honest, I'm very new in the unit test and I don't know how to do it, so that's why I need help for the unit test to have an idea how it works...

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your question.

But it looks like you want to disable the Enter function?

Try it:

```js
jQuery(function() {
         jQuery("#myForm").bind("keypress", function(a) {
            if (a.keyCode == 13) {
    alert("Enter detected!");
                return false;
            }
        });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm">
<input type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

"Branch not covered" is telling you that there are possible inputs you have not written a test for.

In your test, `e.charCode` is truthy (`13 == true`). But your app code indicates it is possible for `e.charCode` to be falsey (`0`, `''`, `undefined`, etc.).

You have not tested for the case in which `e.charCode` is falsey and `e.keyCode` is truthy. You have not written a test for when `e.charCode` and `e.keyCode` are both falsey. Write tests for both of these scenarios and your tests will cover all branches.

Comment: ... so you know how I can test the both scenarios ??? Seriously I don't know unit test... this is the first time that I need to define/test a scenario.

Comment: You can test for charCode 13 by basically duplicating the code inside your test. For the 1st half of test, remove `charCode: 13` from the object. For second half, remove `keyCode: 13` from the object. 

Then make a whole new test for "should not intercept other keypress events". Start by copying your current test, then change the keyCode and charCode to something else, and then negate all your assertions.

Comment: correction: Your 2nd separate test should be for "should not intercept if both keyCode and keyDown are missing".  Copy your initial test and remove keyCode and charCode completely (meaning `undefined`) and then negate all your assertions.